# Simplifying PowerPoint Template to Remove Effects, Layers etc

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using a PowerPoint template (and a very old version of PowerPoint - 2007).

When the presentation is played, the text on a slide comes in stages as I move through. I want to “flatten” (if that's the right word) the presentation, so that when playing the presentation, there is only one “page” for each slide, so “what you see is what you get” – i.e. only what I see on each slide when preparing it is what gets displayed in the presentation, with no animations, effects, etc...

Is this possible please, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: hi. Welcome to GDSE. PowerPoint isn't really a graphic design tool. Might be better to ask MS Office questions over at SuperUser for future reference. Anyway, I found [this on the Microsoft Office Support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-remove-or-turn-off-animation-effects-fb8a3ab0-f651-45e0-b5f0-b18ba2e7c711#:~:text=Turn%20Off%20all%20Animations%20in%20PowerPoint%20365%20in,Show%20options%2C%20select%20Show%20without%20animation.%20See%20More.) but its for a more recent version. Hopefully it's similar.

Comment: @RobinAndrews Late to the party, sorry, but I think what you need to do is remove any animations on your slides. That'd be what causes shapes to appear one at a time. You haven't mentioned which version you use, but there should be an animation menu item or tab on the toolbar or similar. Or ... probably much simpler ... in the Set Up Slide Show dialog box, choose "Show without animations"